# I cannot get links in the header to center along the cross axis on a Flex-Row, left to right assignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/totoroeatsramen/pen/Vwyebod)

I am doing the Odin Project course. I'm on the flex box section and a little confused. I am not sure what I am doing wrong with aligning along the cross axis in Flex, left to right.

So in the code, I need the "one two three" and "four five six" to be centered on the cross access.

I tried align-content/items, though I think I am suppose to be using items.  I have tried center, flex-start / flex-end to see if it moves, it does not move on the cross at all.

I have googled quite a bit, trying for about an hour while I am working to try different things. Nothing seems to work.  I was having trouble spacing them, however I was able to fix that and the margin to get them off the sides.

My assumption; I think I might be missing something about height?  Does the container not have enough positive space to move around in? Is it so tight vertically that I AM centering but do not see it as the top and bottom are against the content / links as I took away padding and margin?

```css
.header {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: papayawhip;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: tomato;
  background: white;
  padding: 4px 32px;
  margin: 0em 3em 0em 3em;
}

ul {
  /* this removes the dots on the list items*/
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  padding: 8px;
  /* this removes the line under the links */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flex Header</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="left-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class="right-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SIX</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Swap `align-content: center;` for `align-items: center;` on header.

Comment: Thanks!  Appreciate it.  Yea that did the trick too!  I guess when I was creating that, I forgot what content / item did.  Going back to MDN to re-read that section.

Comment: Please consider adding a self-answer (unless it has already been given in an existing answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `height: 100%;` to `ul`  to make the centering you already have effective for the full height of its parent:

```css
.header {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: papayawhip;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: tomato;
  background: white;
  padding: 4px 32px;
  margin: 0em 3em 0em 3em;
}

ul {
  /* this removes the dots on the list items*/
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  padding: 8px;
  /* this removes the line under the links */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flex Header</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="left-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class="right-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SIX</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this 100% fixed the issue I was having!    Ill go read up on why height: 100% does that trick :D   

But my basic understanding, is that its making the UL use 100% of the container height that it is in?    

I appreciate you, thank you.

Comment: @TotoroEatsRamen Yes, that's it. Without that setting, the height of the ul (in which the texts are centered) is lower than the header div, so when you make it 100% high, the already active vertical centering really applies to the full height of the header, because the ul is now as high as the header.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it! It seems also, I added content, instead of items to the header which, probably was my first mistake. 

But ya, I appreciate it! Thank you again.  I learned something new, more than I asked today and for that, I appreciate you! :D

Answer (score 0):

for header class you have taken `display:flex; justify-content: center; align-content: center;` but have to give `align-items:center;` so that the elements which are inside the header class will come vertical center(cross axis - center)..

you have to change your header class css to this:-

```css
.header  {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: papayawhip;
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; /* change this line */
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!   I appreciate it, that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want like this:
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ndDV.png)

add align-items:center;  to .header

.header will be like this:

```
.header {
font-family: monospace;
background: papayawhip;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center; }
```

Comment: This also worked too!  Thanks :D